# How can I convert a pointer to a reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, type-conversion

I have a function:

```
bool IntersectBoxBox(IShape3D* a, IShape3D* b)
    {
        Box* boxA = (Box*)a;
        Box* boxB = (Box)b;

        return(boxA->Intersects(boxB));
    }
```

and it's called when the 2 **IShape3D**'s are determined to be a `box` and a `box` type (there is a `IShape3D->GetType()` method).

Anyways,the problem is that **Intersects** takes a `Box& box`,so I can't pass it a pointer. Is there an cheap way to convert the arguments?

Comment: FYI: You may be interested in using the [visitor pattern to simulate double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C.2B.2B) as an alternative to having to downcast from the interface to a concrete type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just dereference your pointer (`*boxB`).

Answer (score 3):

You can't in general – this is only possible when you have a non-`nullptr`. That may indeed be quite relevant when dynamic casting is involved here, as it seems (don't use C-style casts for dynamic dispatch). After eliminating the `nullptr` case, you may indeed simply dereference the pointer, `*boxB`.